# Swift Bridging Header not finding classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I have some Objective-C files that are imported into a swift bridging header. Some files that I added a while ago are working perfectly but I added some more files today and in Swift code none of the classes in the new files are found at all, as in a 'unresolved identifier' error shows. What could be the reason for this?

These new classes are successfully imported and used in other Objective-C files in the same target and project. I have checked that they are imported in the target, they are also included in Build Phases/Compile Sources.

I am not sure what else to check, any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have to comment with this: Make sure you've cleaned, built and maybe even restarted Xcode..

Comment: This problem typically arises when you have an import into the Swift bridging header _and_ the Objective-C code files are importing the `-Swift.h` header. Is that the case here?

Comment: I am only using Objective-C code in Swift, not the other way around Matt.